# Converting nested List of Lists into a Stream of Streams

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I've got the problem with nested Collection conversion to nested Stream.

I was trying to convert each element of a list into a stream with forEach, but since I'm not that good with Java 8 Streams, I didn't managed to get it working.

```java
List<List<String>> nestedLists = new ArrayList<>();

[...] filling up List with data as List<String>

Stream<Stream<String>> results = [???]
```

My goal is to return results var.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
nestedLists.stream() // Stream<List<Stream>>
    .map(Collection::stream) // Stream<Stream<String>>
```

Comment: That was simple, thank you :) I need to finally learn about Streams